# JavaCompiler interface usage and its default implementation

Tags: java, java-compiler-api, dynamic-compilation

I'm trying to understand how default `JavaCompiler` implementation, the one you can get by invoking `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()`.

How do you use it with a `JavaFileManager`?

I understand that the compiler uses the file mananger it's given (through one of the arguments of `getTask` method) to search for the source files, and to decide where to put the compiled output - but how?

For sources for example, does it use `getJavaFileForInput()` method or `getFileForInput()`?

How do I use the `DiagnosticListener`? 
I passed a `DiagnosticListener` object to the `getTask` method, and even though the compilation failed, nothing was written to this object.

How can I debug what am I doing wrong?

Is there anywhere that tell in details how the **default compiler** uses `getTask` arguments? Not what's written in JavaDoc.